# Node res.send() not working when executed inside callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express, callback

Tried various techniques now to no prevail, can anybody shed any light on this.

```
//Google search -------------------
app.get("/google/:name", function (req, res) {
var term = req.params.name;

var searchTerm = function (search, callback) {
    var options = {
        hostname: "ajax.googleapis.com",
        path: "/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q="+ search + ""
    };

    var gsaReq = http.get(options, function (response) {

        var completeResponse = '';

        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            completeResponse += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function() {
            outputResult(completeResponse);
        });

    }).on('error', function (e) {

        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);

    });
}(term, outputResult);

function outputResult(result){

    console.log(result);

    res.send(result);
    // res.send('hello world');
};

});
```

This works fine if the `res.send()` sends `hello world` just not the `result` of my call back, despite the result being a string? Any ideas?

**If the above doesn't make sense the code below is simplified (without the callback) and the res.send() still fails..?**

The res.send doesn't work without the callback - ahhh:

```js
app.get("/google/:name", function (req, res) {

    var term = req.params.name;

    var searchTerm = function (search) {
        var options = {
            hostname: "ajax.googleapis.com",
            path: "/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q="+ search + ""
        };

        var gsaReq = http.get(options, function (response) {

            var completeResponse = '';

            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                completeResponse += chunk;
            });

            response.on('end', function() {
                res.send(completeResponse);
            });

        }).on('error', function (e) {

            console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);

        });
    }(term);


});
```

Comment: Even without the callback the res.send() does not function:

Comment: Are you using express? Please tag your question with it.

Comment: Are you calling `res.send()` multiple times?

Comment: no res.send is only being called once..

Comment: It appears that changing res.send() to res.write() works. However.. I really have no idea why? Any explanation would be great... Thanks for the input so far. Thanks J